# Refer to attributes from multiple selector in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a bunch of DIVs identified by class screen-cat-comment and I want for each div to execute a plugin that receives as a parameter an attribute value from each DIV.

```
<div class="screen-cat-comment" catId="1"></div>
<div class="screen-cat-comment" catId="2"></div>
<div class="screen-cat-comment" catId="3"></div>
```

then, the selector

```
$('.screen-cat-comment').fragment({ code: $(this).attr('catId') });
```

Passing catId to myPlugin doesn't work -- from the current code, $(this).attr('catId') returns undefined. Is there any way to re-write this selector to pass attr('catId') to the plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` in that context is probably the `window`...

```
$('.screen-cat-comment').each(function(){
    $(this).fragment({ code: $(this).attr('catId') });
});
```